# java netbeans customized print layout

Tags: java, layout, netbeans, printing, customization

Is there a tutorial out there that could help me customize my printing layout? Because I can't seem to find one.

If possible printing the panel itself or printing the table's contents but a customized one.

Thanks in advance.
And sorry still a beginner at java programming.
And also we're using netbeans.

Comment: Which printing layout? Which panel? Which table? Please provide more details...

Comment: We want to have a customize look for a receipt to be printed.
Our 1st option is we created a separate panel for that receipt which if possible could be printed as well as the design created in that panel.
Or maybe our 2nd option that we just print the contents of a table where those contents consist of data for the receipt but we want is to be attractive receipt but unfortunately I couldn't find some tutorials that could make a customize layout for the receipt.

Comment: Sorry for troubles. Still a noob in java programming.